# Do twoway bindings work on iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, mvvm-light

I can't seem to get a twoway binding working on iOS with Mvvm Light but it's fine on Android.

```
// ViewModel property

public string Username
{
  get { return _username; }
  set { _username = value; RaisePropertyChanged(() => Username); }
}

// Android View code
_emailBinding = emailAddress.SetBinding(() => App.Locator.LoginViewModel.Username,
                                        () => emailAddress.Text, 
                                        BindingMode.TwoWay)
```

Using the same binding code on iOS where the emailAddress is a TextField means that the Text value entered is not reflected in the value of the ViewModel Username. 
I can't find any examples like this in the Mvvm Light samples. Has anyone got this to work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 emailAddress.EditingChanged += (s, e) => { };
 emailAddress.ValueChanged += (s, e) => { };

emailAddress.SetBinding(() => App.Locator.LoginViewModel.Username,                                       () => emailAddress.Text, BindingMode.TwoWay)
                .UpdateTargetTrigger("EditingChanged")
                .UpdateTargetTrigger("ValueChanged");
```